# Tag [c++11] does not highlight code samples

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I've seen a couple of questions tagged with only [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and not [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). The code samples in these questions are not automatically highlighted. Should they be? Or should the questions be edited to include the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Code Language for the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tag was set to the default value of None.  I updated it to `lang-cpp`, so that should fix the problem.

Here's an example:  [C++11 - templates, friends, decltype & access modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016885/c11-templates-friends-decltype-access-modifiers)  It looks like it worked to me.  (Are there any inconsistencies that need to be addressed?)

Comment: Shouldn't you mark it as *status-completed* ?

Comment: @Martin Got it, thanks.  I was just searching for an example to edit in.